# Plot (fill color) map with USA states data in R

Tags: r, dictionary, plot

I have following data which I want to plot on States map of the USA:

```
x = data.frame(state.x77[,"Income"])
```

How can I plot these as color fill in states on a map?

I can plot the map:

```
map("state", boundary=TRUE, col=colorRampPalette(c("blue","green","yellow","red"))(50), fill=T)
```

I can match the states:

```
match(map("state",plot=F)$names, tolower(rownames(x)))
```

I tried to modify example from ?map_data :

```
if (require("maps")) {
states <- map_data("state")
arrests <- USArrests
names(arrests) <- tolower(names(arrests))
arrests$region <- tolower(rownames(USArrests))

choro <- merge(states, arrests, sort = FALSE, by = "region")
choro <- choro[order(choro$order), ]
qplot(long, lat, data = choro, group = group, fill = assault,
  geom = "polygon")
qplot(long, lat, data = choro, group = group, fill = assault / murder,
  geom = "polygon")
}
```

But I am not able to adjust it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to merge your arrests data with your map data. You can pass the map data separately to a `geom_map` layer. Try

```
x = data.frame(region=tolower(rownames(state.x77)), 
    income=state.x77[,"Income"], 
    stringsAsFactors=F)

states_map <- map_data("state")
ggplot(x, aes(map_id = region)) + 
    geom_map(aes(fill = income), map = states_map) +
    scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("blue","green","yellow","red")) + 
    expand_limits(x = states_map$long, y = states_map$lat)
```

Comment: The arrest data is only from example in ?map_data. I was only trying to modify it. I want to plot x (x<-data.frame(state.x77[,"Income"])) My code should not have any need for 'arrests' data.

Comment: @rnso Sorry about that. I forgot to scroll up higher. I've update the example to work with the state.x77 income data.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Only that I wanted to use this color palette: col=colorRampPalette(c("blue","green","yellow","red"))(some_number)

Comment: @rnso I'm not sure it looks that great, but there you are. Please read the `ggplot2` documentation for further customization options.

Comment: Is `map_data` in `ggplot2`?  I was looking for it a little earlier.

Comment: @RichardScriven Yes. `map_data` is a function in the `ggplot2` package.

Comment: @MrFlick: Thanks. What colour scheme do you suggest for this data?

Comment: @rnso I'm afraid suggesting colors isn't my speciality.