# How to map a single US state (MO) county population data using maps package?

Tags: r, maps

I'm having difficulty mapping gradient colors to some county-level population data I have using the base R package maps.  I know that colors must be interpolated to the dataframe, but I'm not sure how that is then translated to the map.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
library(dplyr)
require(maps)

my_fake_data <- data_frame(
  county = sample(c('list','of','all','counties'),115,T),
  county_population = sample(1:1000000,115,T))

grey_black <- colorRampPalette(c('grey50','black'))

map_data <- my_fake_data %>% 
  arrange(county_population) %>%
  mutate(county_population_color = grey_black(nrow(.)))

map('county','missouri',interior = T,fill =T,
col = grey_black(map_data$county_population_color))
```

How do I tell R to map colors in the correct order?  My sense tells me to attach my data to map's internal database, but I can't find the documentation to do it correctly - - or, more likely, I'm just wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24399367/plot-fill-color-map-with-usa-states-data-in-r) might be helpful.

Comment: try `col = grey_black(10)` where 10 is the number of colors between `grey50` and `black`

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you will need to access the county.fips data frame contained in the maps package.  This will have the fips number and the state, county name.  This list is in the correct order for mapping.  The code example below extracts the Missouri counties and randomly colors a couple for verification:

```
mocounties<-county.fips[grepl('missouri', county.fips$polyname),]
  mocounties$col<-"grey"
  mocounties$col[5]<-"red"
  mocounties$col[15]<-"green"
  mocounties$col[115]<-"blue"

map('county','missouri', interior = T,fill =T,
    col = mocounties$col)
```